# Draw sphere and add scattered data with color information

Tags: pgfplots, plot, 3d

My goal is to plot 3D data (x,y,z coordinates) such that a certain path on/inside a unit ball is illustrated. Since the path will not only be on the surface of the unit ball I have to encode the norm of $(x,y,z)$ as color. Plotting the path alone works quite well using pgfplots. The output file format should be eps/pdf (preferably eps). [Here](http://pastebin.com/ntqwn3X6) is a link to pastebin, where I have put some example data (`example.dat`).

Currently I am using the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\tikzset{mark size=.5}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.misc,shapes.arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows,patterns,}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      ticks=none,
      xmin=-1,xmax=1,
      ymin=-1,ymax=1,
      zmin=-1,zmax=1
      ]
      \addplot3[scatter,scatter src=explicit] file {example.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which shows the colored data as I want (neglecting labels). I am not able to include a sphere for better visualization. The sphere+path should look somewhat like [this](http://www.hull.ac.uk/php/455230/images/science_pix/Fig2_LHS_poeltl_control.jpg)(except labels/nodes).

The sphere should preferably look like in the link above (shaded) but something like in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124936) answer would also be okay with fewer grid lines (like 3-4). I tried to add the plot from the answer but I do not get the opacity at all, even if I compile only the answer code itself.

I compile my figures using the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Give name of .tex file as argument to the command prompt (./compileFigure name_of_tex)

latex $1.tex
dvips -E $1.dvi -o temp.eps
epstool --copy --bbox temp.eps $1.eps
rm *.aux *.log *.dvi temp.eps
```

What am I missing here to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! The missing opacity support might be related to the driver, i.e. to `epstool`. Have you tried to omit `epstool`? Does the problem appear with `pdflatex` as well?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Yes, it does also happen if I just use `pdflatex myfile.tex`. Sorry, forgot to mention that in my question

Comment: Can you list the package versions on your system? I have no problems with opacity. If a package upgrade would solve the problem, that would be fine.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Thanks! Updating pgfplots package helped together with using `pdflatex`. I will put the working code as an answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a no-repro after a package update.

Answer (score 0):

After updating packages opacity now works fine and I am able to comile the following MWE with `pdflatex` to achieve an output like I was looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\tikzset{mark size=.5}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal image,
        ticks=none,
        xmin=-1,xmax=1,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        zmin=-1,zmax=1,
        colormap/blackwhite
        ]
    \addplot3[%
        opacity = 0.2,
        surf,
        z buffer = sort,
        samples = 21,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal image,
        ticks=none,
        xmin=-1,xmax=1,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        zmin=-1,zmax=1
        ]
    \addplot3[scatter,scatter src=explicit] file {example.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, some finetuning is needed. But in principle this is what I was looking for.